# Обработка входного аргумента jstring в Android Studio NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

Здравствуйте,

в приложении под андроид (Android Studio) возникла необходимость использования NDK . Однако появились следующие затруднения.

В файле с++ (папка jni) имеется функция

```
   #define sd  0x0F

   jint
   Java_com_bignerdranch_android_newmyndkproj_MainActivity_intFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring str)
  {
       //Здесь нужно взять строку str сравнить с другой строкой с помощью if
       // и вернуть дефайн sd если истина.

   return ;
}
```

Вот с телом этой функции и возникла проблема. Нужно сравнить входную строку **str** с другой строкой и если истина вернуть define **sd**. Если перевести все это в java код то должно быть примерно следующее:

```
      int sd = 0x0F;
      if (str.equals("reg785")){
          return sd;
      }
      else{
          return 0;
      }
```

Как обработать тип **jstring** чтобы его можно было сравнивать с заранее известной строковой переменной?

Java activity которая использует **intFromJNI** выглядит следующим образом:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("my-jni");
}

public native String intFromJNI();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    int testInt = intFromJNI(String str);




    TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


   mainText.setText( Integer.toString(intFromJNI("reg785")) );



}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать тело функции **intFromJNI** чтобы можно было сравнить входную строку **str** типа **jstring** с заранее известной строкой, например "reg785" ?

Заранее большое спасибо всем за ответы.

---

Comment: [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23126682/3240681) способ перевода jstring в char*. Для сравнения сишных строк можно использовать strcmp.

Comment: @alexolut, большое спасибо за ответ. Проблема решена, с некоторой корректировкой. Ответ изложен в основном вопросе.

Comment: лучше оформите ответ именно как ответ, так будет проще его найти.

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ на мой вопрос (большое спасибо @alexolut):**

Когда я набрал в теле функции **intFromJNI** код

```
 const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, JNI_FALSE);
```

У меня вышла ошибка:
"request for member 'getstringutfchars' in something not a structure or union"

После некоторых поисков нашел решение проблемы  в [англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181934/jni-converting-jstring-to-char/23126682#23126682).

Т.е. строка должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
   const char *res = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, JNI_FALSE);
```

В результате тело функции должно быть:

```
 #define sd  0x0F

 jint
   Java_com_bignerdranch_android_newmyndkproj_MainActivity_intFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring str)
 {
    const char *res = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, JNI_FALSE);;


    if(strcmp(res, "reg785") == 0){
       return sd;
    }
    else{
       return 0;
    }
 }
```